# Connect Java to Oracle database in VSCode

Tags: java, database, oracle, ojdbc

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:383)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:376)
```

I have downloaded the `ojdbc8.jar` file and added this line of code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

but it is still not working.

This is my code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","moe");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
```

[image: some images that might help]

I'm trying to connect to a database.

I'm using:

- Java JDK 18.0.1.1
- ojdbc8.jar
- Visual Studio IDE
- Oracle Database

Comment: Delete that `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");` line. You don't need it - the driver loads itself. (And, anyway, that is the wrong class name.) See what error (if any) you get after making that change.

Comment: Related: [JDBC Class.forName vs DriverManager.registerDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5484227/12567365) and [Class.forName still seems necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37876684/12567365)

Comment: What's the right class name? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why.